# How to prove that : $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \arctan(x) + C$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

The question is the title... It would be nice that the demonstration doesn't start from the result but from the indefinite intergral

Comment: what Kind of  Theorems you can use?

Comment: substitute $x=\tan u$

Comment: What is your definition of $\arctan$?

Comment: You forgot the arbitrary constant of integration at the end:
$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}~dx=\arctan(x)\color{red}{+C}$$

Comment: Yest that's right !

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends on what you do want to use (or *can use*), but if it isn't a standard integral you can rely on; substitute $x = \tan t$, then use $1+\tan^2t = \sec^2t$ and $x'(t) = \sec^2t$, so:
$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^2} \, \mbox{d}x \to \int \frac{1}{1+\tan^2t} x'(t)\,  \mbox{d}t = \int \frac{1}{\sec^2t} \sec^2t\,  \mbox{d}t= \int \,  \mbox{d}t = t + C$$
Now if $x = \tan t$, then $t = \ldots$.

Comment: Ok nice one ! I just have a last question : you can substitute $ x = \tan t$ because the function $: x \rightarrow tan(x)$ takes all values in : $]-\infty, +\infty[$ unlike the function : $x\rightarrow \sin(x)$ that takes values in $[-1, 1]$ right ?

Answer (score 0):

I have always taught this by first finding the derivative of $\arctan x$. Or is that what you where trying to avoid?

Let $y=\arctan x$ so $\tan y = x$. Then implicitly differentiate to get:

$$\sec^2 y \cdot y' = 1$$

$$y'=\cos^2y$$

Then consider a right angle triangle with angle $y$ in one corner. As $\tan y=x$ then the adjacent side can be $1$ and the opposite side can be $x$. Using Pythagoras gives the hypotenuses as $\sqrt{1+x^2}$. So $\cos y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and hence:

$$y'=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

The integral then comes from the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid, but nevertheless now I have (thanks to you and StackTD) the two ways to prove that : $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx = \arctan x + C $

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that it limits the domain. You can clearly extend it by periodicity outside of the limits imposed by triangles, but it's worth noting IMO.

Comment: Point taken. The domain of $y$ is $(-1,1)$ and I have only covered the $[0,1)$ case. The negative version is basically the same argument.